# For loop to add jpg images into Tkinter Text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have no problem adding jpg images in sequence using

```
image1 = Image.open("file_path")
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
text.image_create(END, image=photo1)
image2 = Image.open("file_path")
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
text.image_create(END, image=photo2)
....
```

But when I try to display text and images from a text file like:

```
    .... lines .....
    <img>file_path to image 1</img>
    .... lines .....
    <img>file_path for image 2</img>
    .... lines .....
    <img>file_path for image 3</img>
    .... lines .....
```

Using a loop:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0:5] == "<img>":
            file_path = line[5:-7]
            image = Image.open(file_path)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            text.image_create(END, image=photo)
            txt.insert(END, '\n')
```

I get only the lines of text  and in place of images blank areas. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is probably getting destroyed by the garbage collector. Save a reference to the image. For example:

```
images = []
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0:5] == "<img>":
            ...
            images.append(photo)
            ...
```

Comment: Per your suggestion I made a short test script with one function creating an empty list images=[], then parsing the data text line and appending photo to the list each time the tag <img> is found. The second function re-opens the data file and when tag <img> is found item from list is incorporated into Tk.Text => it Works many thanks!